# Upload video file to the Django Backend from Flutter

Tags: mysql, django, flutter, dart, multipart

I have Implemented the mentioned function to upload the video file in the dart file where I add the frontend implementation of uploading video.

```
Future uploadVideo(File videoFile) async {
 var uri = Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.6:8000/videos/");
 var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

 var multipartFile = await MultipartFile.fromPath(
  "video",
  videoFile.path,
 );

 request.files.add(multipartFile);
 StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
 response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
  print('value');
  print(value);
 });
 print(videoFile.path);
 print(response.statusCode);
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print("video uploaded");
 } else {
  print("video upload failed");
 }
}
`
```

While calling this method, Getting the status code 400 (Bad Request). How can I overcome this problem?

Using Xampp Server and Using the MySQL local database in the backend.